# How to bind jquery event to dynamically added multiple DOM elements?

Tags: jquery

[image for reference1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtUX6.png) [images for reference2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dQ6d.png)I'm creating multiple DOM elements dynamically on button `click`.

I'm using jquery `.on()` method to bind 'image cropping plugin' to dynamically added DOM elements, but it works for only first DOM element not for second, third.
On click of first DOM, dialog box is getting open to choose image but not for second DOM element as in shown in picture.

```
$("#add-button").on('click', function() {
  $('#gallery-div').append('<div class="col-md-4"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="gallery-remove">&times;</a><label class="upload_testi remove"><span>Choose file</span><input id="gallery-img" class="crop-dynamic-cls" type="hidden" name="test[image]"></label></div>');

  $(document).on("click", "a.gallery-remove", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#gallery-div', function() {
    $(this).find('label').each(function() {
      $('.crop-dynamic-cls').awesomeCropper({
        width: 1020,
        height: 434,
        debug: true
      });
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: move out the other click events out side of `$("#add-button")` click

Comment: It's working... https://jsfiddle.net/k2fxzsae/ I just remove the `+i+` from the `#add-button` click event

Comment: You have two event delegation definitions - are you referring to this one `$(document).on('click', '#gallery-div',` ?  That will only work for the first DOM element as IDs must be unique, so using `#` will always only find the first one.

Comment: @Roy OPs code is incomplete and the `i` doesn't appear to have anything to do with it not working for OP: https://jsfiddle.net/ymrg4Lpj/

Comment: @lorem_ipsum your code works fine (more-or-less) as presented (as shown by the above 2 fiddles).  Can you provide a working snippet that demonstrates the problem?  [mcve] (or be more specific as to where the issue is as it's a bit vague)

Comment: The last event handler does:  loop each label inside gallery-div, then update all .crop-dynamic-cls regardless of where they are - the find/each are redundant unless the `$(".crop-dynamic-cls")` is meant to be `$(".crop-dynamic-cls", this)`

Comment: It's almost always wrong to bind an event handler inside another event handler. Every time you click, you add an additional handler to all the elements that were created earlier.

Comment: The whole point of event delegation is that you do it once, and it automatically works for all the dynamically-added elements. You don't need to do it again each time you add an element.

Comment: `#gallery-div` isn't being added dynamically, it appears to be the static element that you're appending all the new elements to. So you don't need to use event delegation for it.

Comment: See images for references, DOM is getting created but on click the dialog box is getting triggred.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, also check I have changed the selector to .gallery-remove, not a.gallery-remove

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // first register your handler for all future added elements to the DOM

  $(document).on("click", ".gallery-remove", function() {
    console.log('remove the parent');
  });

  // Then register the handler that will add stuff to the DOM
  $("#add-button").on('click', function() {
      $('#gallery-div').append('<div class="col-md-4"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="gallery-remove">&times;</a><label class="upload_testi remove"><span>Choose file</span><input id="gallery-img' + i + '" class="crop-dynamic-cls" type="hidden" name="test[image]"></label></div>');
  // do other stuff here
  });
});
```